# Efficient way to reduceByKey ignoring keys not in another RDD?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a large collection of data in pyspark. The format is key-value pairs, and I need to do a reducebykey operation, but ignoring all data whose key isn't in an RDD of 'interesting' keys that I also have.

I found a solution on SO that utilizes the subtractbykey operation to achieve this. It works, but crashes due to low memory on my cluster. I have not been able to change this with tweaking the settings, so I'm hoping there's a more efficient solution.

Here's my solution that works on smaller datasets:

```
# The keys I'm interested in
edges = sc.parallelize([("a", "b"), ("b", "c"), ("a", "d")])
# Data containing both interesting and uninteresting stuff
data1 = sc.parallelize([(("a", "b"), [42]), (("a", "c"), [60]), (("a", "d"), [13, 37])])
data2 = sc.parallelize([(("a", "b"), [43]), (("b", "c"), [23, 24]), (("a", "c"), [13, 37])])
all_data = [data1, data2]

mask = edges.map(lambda t: (tuple(t), None))
rdds = []
for datum in all_data:
    combined = datum.reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b)
    unwanted = combined.subtractByKey(mask)
    wanted = combined.subtractByKey(unwanted)
    rdds.append(wanted)

edge_alltimes = sc.union(rdds).reduceByKey(lambda a,b: a+b)
edge_alltimes.collect()
```

As desired, this outputs [(('a', 'd'), [13, 37]), (('a', 'b'), [42, 43]), (('b', 'c'), [23, 24])]
(i.e. data for the 'interesting' key tuples have been combined and the rest has been dropped).
The reason I have the data in several RDDs is to mimic behavior on my cluster where I can't load all the data simultaneously due to its size.
Any help would be great.

Comment: You're reimplementing `groupByKey` - almost always a bad idea. And why subtract after reduce? This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Could you clarify how you would do this with the groupByKey-operation? How would you get that to keep only the desired keys?

Comment: Generally I think there are two approaches. 1st - if collection of desired keys is relatively small - you can `broadcast` the collection and then perform `filter` before reduceByKey. 2nd - if collection of desired keys is big - you can use `join` operation on keys (collection of keys must have only unique keys in this case).

Comment: It's much too large to broadcast.
It is not clear to me what you mean by 'use join operation on keys'. Can you give an example that accomplishes this?

Comment: @ahura - i have added Scala code in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example with join. A small drawback is that you need to have RDD of pairs before join and you need to strip extra data after join.

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

object Main {

  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("myapp").setMaster("local[*]")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val goodKeys = sc.parallelize(Seq(1, 2))
    val allData = sc.parallelize(Seq((1, "a"), (2, "b"), (3, "c")))


    val goodPairs = goodKeys.map(v => (v, 0))

    val goodData = allData.join(goodPairs).mapValues(p => p._1)

    goodData.collect().foreach(println)
  }
}
```

Output:

```
(1,a)
(2,b)
```